# Binance Transaction issue, Metamask and Trezor

Tags: metamask, wallets, binance, binance-smart-chain, trezor

transaction from Binance does not appear on my Trezor wallet, MetaMask, or any other third-party wallets. When I search for the transaction history in Etherscan it says that it was successful under the Binance Smart Chain server. Any suggestion on resolving the problem?

Comment: What is the network which your transaction sent on? Is it ethereum or binance smart chain?

Comment: @saman.shahmohamadi; First I sent through a Erc20 and then I tried on Binance smart Chain. None of them appeared in Metamask, even when I switches to the Binance network. But then I figured out that it is a TRC-20 token (BTT to be more specific), so I do not know whether I should use another third-party wallet that supports TRc20...?